# Why do all new words come from English?

Tags: etymology, loanwords

English used to import words from other languages. I was listening to a French station and they used the words 'hate-free zone' and 'selfie'. The last time I remember English using importing a foreign word was [ogooglebar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_(verb)#Ungoogleable) which is Swedish for unsearchable. If influence depends on the number of speakers, wouldn't English be importing words from China? Maybe influence depends on the average GDP of the language speakers?

Comment: Its not so much about the number of speakers in the source language addit is about the number of speakers of the importing language who are exposed to the source language.  Also, of course, a new thing that needs a name often provides the impetus to borrow that name rather than to come up with a novel one (coffee and tea in English; selfie and hot dog in French).

Comment: (*cough*) *paparazzi*, *latte*, and even *macchiato* are recent Italian loanwords, as well as *emoji* and *anime* which originate from Japan. I'm sure there are many others, but these are the first that popped in my mind. As for why, there has been such a boom about coffee culture, it was logical that coffee shops borrowed terms derived from Italy. Japanese culture, cartoons, video games etc is extremely popular with geeks, nerds and the very young. But otherwise, English is very flexible, words can be shortened, combined, blended, clipped, coined very easily.

Comment: They don't.  And how would you know, amyway? How many other languages do you speak, to know that none of them are coining new words or borrowing them from languages other than English?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise. If OP had asked why _so many_ words are borrowed from English  by other languages, it would be worth an answer.

Comment: @Chloe Maybe you should edit the title. I answered without the assumption that _all_ new words come from English, but rather that _most_ new words do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your French example is not as much about influence as it is about how the French language is regulated. [Information on how a new word enters the French language.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise)

In other cases, using English words may be caused by:

1. The increasing number of non-native English speakers outside of English-speaking countries.
2. The strong influence of English-speaking media.
3. The strong economic influence on the world by English-speaking countries (If you want to trade with them, it would help to know their language!).
4. Tourism (this is related to point 4) (This works for English-speaking toursists, or high-toursim spots in English-speaking countries).

This was all I could think of, so I hope this helps!